# Game of Pig function repeating?

Tags: c++, function

For homework we are suppose to progrma a pig game which adds up to 100 points and then declares a winner or loser. The problem im having is when the person rolls a 1 for some reason it rolls again and doesnt go to the computer and lets it roll. I cant figure out what is happening, if the user rolls one it automatically just rolls agian for him.

Comment: Your functions that have an int in the signature should actually return an int. If you compiled with -Wall you would get a wwarning from the compiler for making a function that is not marked void that has no return value

Comment: your code is full of `else if (*alwaystrue*)`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you should see that behavior (unless not returning an int is causing that somehow.  Or the computer is also rolling a 1)

Comment: Hmm you think its cause the computer might be rolling a one? Let me test that

Comment: How cna i get ride of that error?

Comment: Why is the computer rolling a one after i roll one? Isnt that really odd?

Comment: Why is my random numbers gererating the same order every time i run the game?

Comment: @mystycs: the `srand()` function lets you change the starting value.  People usually seed it with `srand(time(NULL))` so it's different each time the program runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shuttle87 says, your `int` functions don't return anything.  Change them to return `void` isntead.

As for your problem:  http://ideone.com/EEkvy During my test, I rolled 1 three times, one of which the computer rolled after, and twice I got two turns in a row.  I'd guess this is because the computer *also* rolled one, and when the computer rolls one, nothing is displayed on the screen.

I've seen this game before.  Isn't the player supposed to only keep their points when they hold?

Comment: Why is my random numbers gererating the same order every time i run the game?

Comment: At the very beginning of `main`, put `srand(time(NULL))`; this will seed the number generator with your system clock.